# Iterate over dataframe using itertuples() with a condition on column values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime

I'm trying to select a range in a dataframe everytime x <= 20 and create a new dataframe with a colum which is the sum of the selected rows (negative value include) of that range and keep the last date as index. Thks for some hints and if I'm on the right way 
This is the output I want and below my approach which is not working.

```
Date         x             Date         sum
2019-01-01   100           2019-01-05   343
2019-01-02   120   --->    2019-01-10   804
2019-01-03    80           2019-01-15   650
2019-01-04    48           2019-01-20   428
2019-01-05     5           ...
2019-01-06   110           ...
2019-01-07   420
2019-01-08   140
2019-01-09   126
2019-01-10     8
2019-01-11    50
2019-01-12   160   
2019-01-13   280
2019-01-14   148
2019-01-15    12
2019-01-16   190
2019-01-17   120
2019-01-18    80
2019-01-19    48
2019-01-20   -10
...
...

#######
for date in df.index.to_series().dt.date.unique():
   for row in df.itertuples():
      for i in row:
         if i <= 20:
           new_df = pd.DataFrame(columns=df.keys())
           new_df.index.name = 'Date'
           new_df ['sum'] = df.sum(axis = 0)
         continue:
```

#

Comment: Someone already suggested an answer that looks good, so what i’ll add is that explicit iteration should be a last resort when working with Pandas. It’s such a powerful library, most use cases are already covered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not use groupby?

```
df.groupby(df['x'].shift().le(20).cumsum()) \
  .agg(Date=('Date','last'), sum = ('x','sum')).set_index('Date')

            sum
Date           
2019-01-05  353
2019-01-10  804
2019-01-15  650
2019-01-20  428
```

Comment: this solution works when 'Date' is not set as an index beforehand because I forgot to mention it, sorry. Because when I use your solution I get this: KeyError: "Column 'Date' does not exist!" Do I have to "unset" the index as a "normal" column before using groupby()

Comment: The simplest way is really to reset_index

Comment: Can you please tell me more about this "le(20)" and what if in case the values of x being all negatives and the condition should be set to x >= -20 (-20 being the largest/biggest one)

Comment: The main idea is to set True at start of each group then cumsum fill 0s to the 1st group, 1 to the 2nd an so on.  You can make an additional column `df['g'] = df['x'].shift().le(20).cumsum()` to select  the formula  giving  the expected groups

Comment: I'm not really sure that I got what you meant! sorry  ... but Thks!